# Trigger.io android native keyboard height detection

Tags: javascript, android, android-softkeyboard, trigger.io

I'm building an app with trigger.io and stumbled upon a problem regarding native keyboards. Contrary to iOS where clicking input box automatically pushes the box upwards and shows the keyboard, in android, keyboard goes over the input box and user can't see what he's writing. What I'm trying to achieve is to find out the height of the native keyboard, which may vary each device, and push the input box manually using javascript above the native keyboard by giving the input box padding-bottom or something similar, equal to keyboards height.
So the question is, is there a way to find out the keyboard height in android using javascript? Or is there any alternative method to achieve the same effect?

FYI: I've checked if the size of the window changes when the keyboard is visible but it doesn't, so checking the window height changes won't help.

This is how my page looks like, before overlapping keyboard: http://puu.sh/7BhGP.png

Comment: Are you developing an Android app? If you are then you could use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your manifest. This will resize your layout when the keyboard is shown. Your input field should be put into view. Note: If you are using a full screen theme then this will not work - it's a bug.

Comment: I'm developing a Trigger.IO app, which by definition works in native browser of android with html5. so I can't use manifest or anything similar unless i'm writing a custom module for trigger.io.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the keyboard did change the window height of my Trigger.io Android app when I built it half a year ago, so this is indeed strange. Maybe things have changed since then? Btw: You can actually change the content of the manifest file after `forge build` and before `forge package`. You can use their hook build system for that. Btw: which viewport meta tag are you using in your index.html?